# would like to find out what kind of frame I have

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can you please help me on identifying this frame has no logo or marks no decals all it has is s serial number[image]

Comment: There is no universal registration of bike serial numbers. Even the number stamped on the frame doesn't necessarily mean much. Your best bet is to figure out the manufacture of the frame, and see if they have a lookup for it. However, all of this is generally irrelevant, as who originally made a bike doesn't have any real bearing on its rideability.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337/24228).  We can't help if you give us zero information.

Comment: That frame is about as generic as they get.

Answer (score 1):

Its a BMX.

Looks like it originally had a back brake, but that has been stripped off.  The rider is/was too big and the saddle is far too high, resulting in a lot of leverage on the seat post which is showing a bend to the rear.  The bars are also tilted forward like a fat-man's belt buckle because the bike was far too small for its rider.

The high spoke count wheels look flashy but will work fine, but this was never a racing BMX.  The pegs on the back suggest it was built for and intended for slow speed stunts.  Whether it was used like that, who knows.

The small chainring implies its a somewhat modern transmission, so likely this century at a guess.

That green paint job looks like a home spray with a rattlecan.  You may be able to wipe the paint off with thinners to restore its factory paint/decals if they're still underneath.